# How can I load python wikipedia image in pygame display?

Tags: pygame, wikipedia

Alright, I am making as title, and here is this is part of codes.

```
black = (0,0,0)
display = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
def main():
   search_word = "apple inc"
   result = ""
   main = True

   while main:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               quit()
       display.blit(black)
       result = wikipedia.page(search_word)
       display.blit(result.images[0], (100, 100)

       pygame.display.update()
```

And, I got error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       display.blit(result.images[0], (100, 100)) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'images'

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix it?

You can fix it by passing a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) object to the [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) function, not a string.

Pygame does not automatically download images from the internet for you. You have to download the images yourself; then you can use the functions in [`pygame.image`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) to create `Surface` instances.